# Schema design for products with different sizes?

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have My Products Table With Many to many relations with variants table

```
------------------------------
| ID | variant name          |
|----------------------------| 
| 1  | XL                    |
| 2  | small                 |
| 3  | custom                |
------------------------------
```

I need if I user Choose custom he should add

```
data for custom
-------------------------------
| length | shoulder_width | chest_size | hip_size | waist_size | sleeves_length| sleeves_width | trouser_length
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| null   | null           | null       | null     | null       | null          | null           | null
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

every user when adding product and choose custom will add all of them or tow or three anyone he like

so how I will make database so every user when adding a custom variant can enable and disable what he likes and how in user area will add data for variant and save it any idea how to make this without Complicate everything

Comment: Will the columns for custom always be the same? Or can it be different for different products?

Comment: @Colin'tHart different for different products